# do not load custom actions assembly

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, setup-project

My setup project installs web site and executes some custom actions using a class library. That class library is copied to bin folder of the web site, and after that IIS tries to load it even though it isn't needed by the web site any how. How to prevent the class library from loading? Maybe it is possible to copy it to another directory instead of bin? Or maybe the web.config can be configured in such a way to prevent that class library from loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved the assembly to another folder and that solved the problem.